# python pydev error

Tags: python, pydev

Whenever I start pydev/eclipse and try to run .py file I have an error:

```
An internal error occurred during: 
"Launching PhD mainWorking.py".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I press `OK` and run again everything is going how it should. The error is not very disturbing, but there is something wrong. I was trying to find what but it has no sense form me.

Anyone have similar issue or know where lies the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an error to me... Do you have some entry in your error log for that? (see: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for details on how to get the contents of the error log)